# bathroom switches into a pir/motion sensor

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan, humidity

I have a two switch box in my bathroom that controls a ceiling fan and light. I bought a TDHOS5, Dual Technology Humidity/PIR Motion sensor with the goal of replacing both switches.

I can’t seem to figure out how to make it work based on the wires in the box

Best I’ve got is making the fan work by itself and then connecting the oldlight switch to the black and sharing the white neutral, but when I do that the fan only works when the light is turned off. Help me reduce the right two switches down to one please [image]

Comment: Is replacing the wiring in the wall an option?

Comment: I mean, I was looking for an easier solution. So no I don’t want to replace the wiring. Im frankly ok if I can just get the humidity sensor to control the fan and wire the light seperate. Not optimal but ok

Comment: So there are 3 switches in the box presently, and each one is connected to the black & white of one cable??? These are **switch loops**, they won't play with that controller.

Comment: Correct, three switches and each to the black and white of one cable. Guess I need to return the switch. Thanks.